# how do you set a custom name for a file being uploaded to google drive via API call?

Tags: node.js, api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a text file to google drive via API call. I am working low level, so I don't use any external libraries. I send HTTPS Request, the file gets uploaded on Google Drive along with the content, but the document name is "Untitled". I am able to change the name in a separate HTTPS request using PATCH method, but I want to know if it is possible to set the name before sending the initial HTTPS request. Below is my the header file and HTTPS code I am sending, I would appreciate it if you can help me set the name anything other than "Untitled" .

```
const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `${token_credential.token_type} ${token_credential.access_token}`,
            "Content-Type":'text/plain' ,
        },
        body: {
            name:"MyTextFile.txt"
        }
    }
    let makeFileRequest=https.request(
        sendDriveTask,
        options,
        (res, err) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("success", res.statusCode)
            }
        }
    )
    makeFileRequest.end(filecontent);
}
```

Below is the respond I get back from google drive:
{"kind":"drive#file","id":"1XBcb9q8Q__b6gIP0sH5oOhZOKQMezlIK","name":"Untitled","mimeType":"text/plain"}

Comment: Can you provide the value of `sendDriveTask` you are using?

Comment: It is the endpoint that the documentation provide:                                                    const sendDriveTask = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your endpoint. About `I am trying to upload a text file to google drive via API call.`, when I saw your script, the text data is not included. In your goal, you want to create a text file with empty content. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By guessing your goal, I proposed 2 patterns in an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From your showing script, I understood that you want to achieve your goal using `https.request`. In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- About `I am trying to upload a text file to google drive via API call.`, when I saw your script, the text data is not included. If you want to create a text file with empty content, please modify the endpoint.
- If you want to create a text file with the text content, please include the text data.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, a text file with empty content is created.

```js
const https = require("https");

const token_credential = {
  token_type: "Bearer",
  access_token: "###", // Please set your access token.
};
const sendDriveTask = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
const body = JSON.stringify({ name: "MyTextFile.txt" });
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `${token_credential.token_type} ${token_credential.access_token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};
let makeFileRequest = https.request(sendDriveTask, options, (res) => {
  res.on("data", (r) => {
    console.log(r.toString());
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    console.log("Done.");
  });
});
makeFileRequest.on("error", (e) => {
  console.log(e.message);
});
makeFileRequest.write(body);
makeFileRequest.end();
```

- When this script is run, a text file of "MyTextFile.txt" with empty content is created in the root folder.

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, a text file with sample text content is created. In this case, the request body is sent as `multipart/related`.

```js
const https = require("https");

const metadata = JSON.stringify({ name: "MyTextFile.txt" }); // Please set the file metadata.
const textData = "sample text data"; // Please set the sample text content.

const token_credential = {
  token_type: "Bearer",
  access_token: "###", // Please set your access token.
};
const sendDriveTask = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart";
const boundary = "sample123";
const body = [`--${boundary}\r\n`, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n", metadata + "\r\n", `--${boundary}\r\n`, "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n", textData + "\r\n", `--${boundary}--`].join("");
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `${token_credential.token_type} ${token_credential.access_token}`,
    "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary,
  },
};
let makeFileRequest = https.request(sendDriveTask, options, (res) => {
  res.on("data", (r) => {
    console.log(r.toString());
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    console.log("Done.");
  });
});
makeFileRequest.on("error", (e) => {
  console.log(e.message);
});
makeFileRequest.write(body);
makeFileRequest.end();
```

- When this script is run, a text file of "MyTextFile.txt" with the sample text of `sample text data` is created in the root folder.

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that your access token can be used for creating a file on Google Drive. Please be careful about this.
- About the 2nd pattern, the maximum file size is 5 MB. When you want to upload more sizes, please use the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#resumable)

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)

Comment: Thank you but after running this , I still have the same problem: a file named "untitled" is created on google drive.  I want it to be named "MyText.txt" for instance..

Comment: @Moe Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Thank you but after running this , I still have the same problem: a file named "untitled" is created on google drive. I want it to be named "MyText.txt" for instance..`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed scripts, I can confirm that a text file with the filename of `MyTextFile.txt` is created. So, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Moe But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Moe Although I tested my proposed scripts several times again, unfortunately, I cannot still replicate `but after running this , I still have the same problem: a file named "untitled" is created on google drive.`. I deeply apologize for this again. So, in this case, it is required to confirm the method for correctly replicating your issue. Can you provide the detailed flow for replicating your situation?

Comment: I literally copy and paste what you have proposed on my machine , run it but for some reason I still get "untitled" document on the drive.

Comment: @Moe Thank you for replying. About `I literally copy and paste what you have proposed on my machine , run it but for some reason I still get "untitled" document on the drive.`, unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for it? By this, I would like to test your flow.

Comment: @Moe By the way, from `I literally copy and paste what you have proposed on my machine , run it but for some reason I still get "untitled" document on the drive.`, I couldn't confirm which pattern did you test. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the pattern you tested?

Comment: I tested the Modified script 1 you proposed. I really appreciate it

Comment: @Moe Thank you for replying. About `I tested the Modified script 1 you proposed.`, when I tested my proposed 1st one. A new text file without the text content is created with the filename of `MyTextFile.txt`. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? I would like to confirm your flow.